# Dot Product Question

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Can $u \cdot v=-7$ if $||u||=3$ and $||v||=2$ ?

Comment: If it did, what would that imply $\cos$ of the angle between them would be?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says $|u\cdot v|\leq|u|\cdot|v|$. Does this pose a problem?

---

A proof of Cauchy-Schwarz. By definition, for any real number $x$,
$$
0\leq(u-xv)\cdot(u-xv)=(u\cdot u)-2(u\cdot v)x+(v\cdot v)x^2=|u|^2-2(u\cdot v)x+|v|^2x^2.
$$
The rightmost expression above is a quadratic in $x$. That this quadratic is nonnegative for all real $x$ implies that the discriminant is nonnegative:
$$
0\geq4(u\cdot v)^2-4|u|^2|v|^2\iff (u\cdot v)\leq |u||v|.
$$

Comment: Who knew Kim Jong Un was so fluent in mathematics!

Comment: (A student at this level may not have seen Cauchy-Schwarz.)

Comment: yes...
I've never heard of that though, why must that be so?

I was also just thinking that u⋅v=||u||||v||costheta
=6costheta
so costheta would have to be 1.16 which is not possible, so it doesnt work

Comment: @SimonS The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can be (and usually is) proved immediately after the definition of the dot product so I dont see a problem. For completeness, I'll add a proof for OP's benefit.

Comment: Given that the original poster just said s/he didn't know what C-S was, my point is borne out.

Comment: @SimonS Cauchy-Schwarz (for dot products) shows up in most introductory linear algebra courses in the context of questions like these. Even if the OP doesn't know it, usually they know that $a\cdot b = \|a\|\,\|b\|\cos\theta$ from which CS immediately follows.

Comment: @SimonS It's not necessarily bad to provide an answer that involves a tool that is *slightly* more advanced that what the OP knows. In particular, now that I  have proved the tool, the answer is self-contained. Moreover, the thread will also be looked at by people other than the OP.

Answer (score 1):

That would require an extraordinary angle:
$u \cdot v=-7=||u||~||v||\cos \alpha = 6 \cos \alpha ~~~\Leftrightarrow ~~~\cos \alpha < -1 $

Answer (score 0):

Hint (almost an answer, indeed):

$$\|u+v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2+2u\cdot v=9+4-14=-1$$